# Concurrent programming operation order

Tags: unix, concurrency, operating-system

I'm studying an operating system class and i'm trying to understand how concurrent programming works.

The only thing that i really can't figure it out is to understand the "order" of the operation/instruction execution of two or more process:

For example, given this code for two process trying to access a critical section

[image]

from `Parbegin`, what is the order of the execution of this code? 
They operate in a 1:1 manner (like, one row of code is executed alternated by Process1 and Process2 like 1,1, 2,2, 3,3...n,n with the obviously entry/exit point condition) or there is some particoular order that i'm missing?

For what i have understood, the execution is something like that:

```
 var and turn inizialized
turn is equal to 1 then P1 enter in the CS
turn is equal to 1 then P2 enter the while
P2 is now in busy-wait
P1 is doing the critical section
P1 exit from the critical section and set turn=2
P2 exit from the while and enter CS
P1 doing remainder
P2 exit CS and set turn=1
P1 can enter the cycle
```

and so on. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did this example come from? It is very poorly done.

Comment: Operating Systems - Dhamdhere, Critical Section access algorithmic approach.

Comment: This is completely unrealistic. No wonder it is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important feature of concurrency, and the source of many difficulties, is that **the order of operations across processes is not known**. The order of operations is [non-deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminacy_in_concurrent_computation).

To a first approximation, you can think of the order of operations as random. That is, consider that the processor (more precisely, the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Process_scheduler)) executes the multiprocess program as follows:

- Randomly pick one of the processes.
- Execute one instruction from that process.
- Repeat.

The processor might execute one instruction from each process in turn. Or it might execute 2½ loops from process 1, then 3 instructions from process 2, than resume process 1 for a while, a bit more of process 2, etc. Or it might execute 3 instructions from process 1, then 1 from process 2, then 4 from process 1, then 1 from process 2, then 5 from process 1, etc. Or it might keep executing process 1 forever.

The goal of the study of concurrency is to determine properties of programs that are true no matter what the sequence of random picks is, or at least for a class of random picks that are “not too extreme”. The most common type of “not too extreme” class is [fairness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_nondeterminism#Fairness) assumptions, which roughly speaking means that every instruction that isn't blocked (a blocked instruction is something like an input instruction waiting for an input event) will get executed eventually. This rules out “executing process 1 forever”, but none of the other examples above.

Regarding the algorithm you quote in particular, its goal is that only one of the processes can be between the start and the end of the critical section. (Note that although the critical section is written on a single line, it generally consists of multiple instructions.) This property is desired no matter how the instructions from the two processes are interleaved.

There are several simplifications in my answer. In particular, [randomness and non-determinism are actually different concepts](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/632/what-is-the-difference-between-non-determinism-and-randomness). With a random scheduler, you may or may not get lucky, and if not you can try again, whereas a non-deterministic scheduler may be out to get you. A random scheduler is in fact somewhat fair, whereas a real-world scheduler may not be fair at all. The important thing to internalize about concurrency is that you cannot predict the behavior of the program in advance: there are many possible behaviors.

Comment: That's a good and well explaied answer.
So, if i get it right, the scheduler choose a process that want to enter in a CS by "fairness", - one of the three rule of Critical Section access (toghether with no busy-wait waiting, and progress) - and it's like flipping a coin; two process have 50/50 to be choosen for execute some set of instruction, but in some way a process will absolutely need to GET him executed - due to his finished timeslice, or due to his state - in some manner.

Comment: Yes schedulers are usually fair. 50/50 is not required what is required is that it is guaranteed that if a process is waiting for processor, then it will have at some time (no starvation).

Comment: @Jean It's more complicated than you make it look. One of the simplifications in my answer is that there are many notions (levels, if you like) of fairness. The "low-level" fairness properties of typical schedulers does not always guarantee a fair execution of the concurrent algorithms we care about. For example, a fair scheduler in the sense you describe does not protect against a livelock.

Comment: @Gilles True in the general case, I know; but in this particular example, nothing more is needed than be able to run in the future.